# Winter Bash の帽子の位置を変えることはできますか？

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

他の人のWinter Bash の帽子を見ていると、
斜めにかぶったり、帽子を逆さにかぶったりしています。
取得した帽子を好きなようにかぶることはできますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「コントロールを表示」にチェックを入れると、カスタマイズできるようになります。

[image: hat editor]

上の画像で上に伸びている茶色いコントロールをドラッグすることで帽子の回転と拡大縮小が、右側の青いコントロールか帽子自体をドラッグすることで位置を調整できます。

Comment: （プロフィールでなく、）Winter Bash の画面で調整できるのですね。ありがとうございました。